# IIS 7.5 giving 404.19 "Denied by filtering rule" if URL contains "test" - No filtering rule defined

Tags: iis-7.5, url, http-status-code-404

my IIS is giving me a 404.19 if a certain URL contains the string "test" in any sort or form. For example:
`http://test2008r2-1/search.php?query=test&type=and&start=1&results=5`

and

`http://test2008r2-1/search.php?query=something&type=and&start=1&categtestory=2,3,4,5,6,13,22,23,24,25,26,33,37`

will both deliver 404.19.

Now, according to [Microsoft Request Filtering Rules](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules) , this means that the request has been blocked by the RequestFiltering module.

So I went to check the RequestFiltering module configuration of the files I am calling and the folders within which they reside. There is nothing about "test" in there. Neither anything even close.

The only rules I have defined are two rules for file-name-expansions (.bat & .rules) which are denied and the default excluded segment "web.config".

But the error feels way too consistent and specific (really only if there is the four letters t,e,s,t all combined and in any place at all), to be a random error. Is there any chance that I can get a full list of applied rules for an element or something simliar, so I can see what gets applied and from where it comes? I am close to looking through all the files manually and checking each one seperately...Since there are a good number of inclusions going on in the script, I hope there is a debugging tool that I am missing...

Any help is greatly appreciated!